# Як перекласти англійською сталий вираз: "Як бідному женитися, то ніч мала"?

Tags: переклад, фразеологізми

More about the expression can be read here: http://storinka-m.kiev.ua/article.php?id=1126

Comment: Перепрошую, зміст Вашого питання: (а) Ви хочете, щоб Вам **пояснили значення** цього виразу (українською чи англійською); чи (б) Ви прекрасно розумієте його сенс, але хочете **знайти англійський еквівалент**? У випадку «а»: будь ласка, перефразуйте це питання (наприклад, «Що означає вираз „…“?» або «What is a meaning of „…“?»). У випадку «б»: це справді на [ELL](http://ell.stackexchange.com/) чи [English](http://english.stackexchange.com/) чи форум перекладачів, а не сюди [хоч питання цікаве в обох випадках].

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Довша версія вислову містить в собі підказку:

> Багатому і чорт маля колисає, а як бідному женитися, то й ніч мала.

Тобто, комусь везе в усьому, а комусь не везе зовсім.

Протиставлення бідних і багатих дуже розповсюджене, тому існують версії з `чорт маля колисає`, де доля бідного полягає у якомусь іншому нещасті - `бідному щипає, щоб плакало`, `вбогий і няньки не знайде`, `бідному і янгол не родич`, та інші. Також, доля багатих може полягати в інших надзвичайних надбаннях - `багатому вітер гроші в очі кидає`, `багатому й чорт горох молотить` - як бачите, народний гумор досить вигадливий.

Можна перекласти сталим висловом `some people have all the luck`.

Answer (score 2):

Згідно [словника фразеологізмів](http://r2u.org.ua/data/%D0%A0%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%96%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE-%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9%20%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%20%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%85%20%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%96%D0%B2%20(1959).pdf) (с. 12):

> Як бідному (сиротині) женитися, то й ніч мала (то й день малий).

Стати ще біднішим, збіднішати.

PS: Не чув раніше цього виразу, дякую за питання!

Comment: У тому словнику "стати ще біднішим" не є поясненням значення вислову.

Comment: Там приводиться кілька схожих виразів, всі з яких можна пояснити.